# Selenium webdriver and database testing

Tags: java, database, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I was looking for the answer on the Internet and I haven't found one so... the thing is: I'm writing automated tests (in java) using selenium and the website that I'm testing has an option of phone number confirmation. 
The user types his phone number, clicks save and to that phone number, we get confirmation code (with an SMS). My question is: how can I test it? Is there any option where I can create a database only for tests or something?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of knowing if your phone has just received a text from a specific number, without your phone being involved in the process.

To cascade test cases like this:

```
assertThat(phoneNoEntered);
assertThat(smsReceived);
```

You need to work with the gateway being used to send SMS. Because honestly, your test scope should be limited from "phoneNo entered" to "Gateway Fired an sms to that number". You don't wanna waste time on deciding if the Phone Subscription service honored your gateway's request, often it depends on user's subscription service.

So find out about the getway, find out if it provides a REST api, and then automate test like this: `assertThat(gatewaySmsId == SOME_IDENTIFIER);`